# Using UIImagePickerController crashes my application on iOS 13

Tags: objective-c, xcode, ios13

As the camera opens, whether I click a photo or not, my app crashes.

The thread that crashes the app is given below:

```
Error : Thread 6 Queue : com.apple.camera.capture-engine.session-queue (serial).
```

My code snippet:

```
-(void)TakePhoto :(id)sender
{
    self.appDelegate.PictureTouchIDByPass = true;

    self.BSomethingChanged = true;

    if([UIImagePickerController isSourceTypeAvailable:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera])
    {
        UIImagePickerController* IPC = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];

        IPC.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
        IPC.cameraCaptureMode = UIImagePickerControllerCameraCaptureModePhoto;
        IPC.cameraDevice= UIImagePickerControllerCameraDeviceRear;
        IPC.showsCameraControls = YES;
        IPC.navigationBarHidden = NO;
        IPC.delegate = self;
        [IPC didReceiveMemoryWarning];
        [IPC setVideoQuality:UIImagePickerControllerQualityTypeIFrame1280x720];

        UIDevice* CurrentDevice = [UIDevice currentDevice];

        while ([CurrentDevice isGeneratingDeviceOrientationNotifications])
        {
            [CurrentDevice endGeneratingDeviceOrientationNotifications];
        }

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^
        {
            [self presentViewController:IPC animated:YES completion:nil];
        });
    }
    else
    {
        [self.appDelegate ShowSingleButtonAlertFromDelegate:NSLocalizedString(@"msg_camera_error", nil) DebugModeError:@""];
    }
}
```

Any help, please!

Comment: Your question is not clear. Please update it.

Comment: @santobedi this is the code i'm using to open the caera into my app. as the camera opens whether i click photo or press the cancel button i goes to my previous screen and after a second the app got crashed with error : Thread 6 Queue : com.apple.camera.capture-engine.session-queue (serial). This thread crashes the app.

Comment: Do you have a crash log in console ?

Comment: Are you testing on real device? Which device is it? Does it support `UIImagePickerControllerQualityTypeIFrame1280x720` for its rear camera? Why are you calling  `[IPC didReceiveMemoryWarning];`? Also, you should look for each properties if it's available on that device (isCameraDeviceAvailable, etc.) Did you allow the camera access?